# Change Service Name on OSB Oracle

Tags: oracle, wsdl, osb

I have an OSB project where it WSDL has the service name: "MyServicePortBindingQSService".
I need change his name to only "MyService", removing the "PortBindingQSService".
Is that possible?

Comment: Check this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20669742/how-wsdl-is-used-in-oracle-service-bus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The proxy and the business was configured to generate the WSDL based on binding, so I changed both of them to based on port.